# What does the keyword "transient" mean in Java?

Tags: java, transient

I saw somewhere

```
transient private TrackDAO trackDAO;
```

Answer (score 274, accepted):

You might first have a look at what [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is.

> It marks a member variable not to be
> serialized when it is persisted to
> streams of bytes. When an object is
> transferred through the network, the
> object needs to be 'serialized'.
> Serialization converts the object
> state to serial bytes. Those bytes are
> sent over the network and the object
> is recreated from those bytes. Member
> variables marked by the java transient
> keyword are not transferred, they are
> lost intentionally.

Example from there, slightly modified (thanks @pgras):

```
public class Foo implements Serializable
 {
   private String saveMe;
   private transient String dontSaveMe;
   private transient String password;
   //...
 }
```

Answer (score 33):

Transient variables in Java are never serialized.

Answer (score 10):

It means that `trackDAO` should not be serialized.