# cant serialize my class Java

Tags: java, class, serialization

It seems like I can't serialize my class called "Ban":

```
class Ban implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        transient Date start;
        transient Date end;
        String explination;
        String from;
        public Ban(Date s, Date e, String ex, String f){
            start = s;
            end = e;
            explination = ex;
            from = f;
        }
    }
```

When I try to print this with a objectoutputstream it gives me an ERROR...
Could you please help me by serializing this class? BTW: What does transient mean?

well it is bukkit but this should do it:

```
[SEVERE] java.io.NotSerializableException: me.bubblegumsoldier.Ban.Main
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at me.bubblegumsoldier.Ban.Main.save(Main.java:113)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at me.bubblegumsoldier.Ban.Main.onDisable(Main.java:247)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:219)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:481)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:400)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:393)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.disablePlugins(CraftServer.java:277)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.stop(MinecraftServer.java:331)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:438)
2013-04-03 19:30:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:573)
```

My saving code looks like this:

The variable:

```
public static HashMap<String, Ban> banned = new HashMap<String, Ban>();
```

The saving part:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
oos.writeObject(banned);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

Comment: What error does it give you? `transient` means that the property should not be serialized.

Comment: What is the error message? Copy and paste it into your question. You probably need to add a public default constructor.

Comment: for transient variable see this:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245600/what-does-the-keyword-transient-means-in-java

Comment: `transient` definition can be found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245600/what-does-the-keyword-transient-means-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have defined Ban as a non-static inner class of another class called Main:

```
public class Main {

    class Ban {
        ...
    }
}
```

This means that every Ban instance has an implicit reference to its outer Main instance. The code above is similar to the following one:

```
public class Main {
    static class Ban {
        private Main main;
    }
}
```

or 
    public class Main {
    }

```
class Ban {
    private Main main;
}
```

So when you serialize a Ban, you're also serializing this implicit instance, which is not serializable, hence the exception.

Make Ban a top-level class, or a static inner class.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the Ban class as posted.  Maybe the error was produced by your class including a Main field variable that is not serializable. But the code posted in the question can be serialized; We can run this:

public class Ban implements Serializable {

```
  transient Date start;
  transient Date end;
  String explination;
  String from;

  public Ban(Date s, Date e, String ex, String f) {
     start = s;
     end = e;
     explination = ex;
     from = f;
  }

  public String toString() {
     return "Ban{" + "start=" + start + ", end=" + end + ", explination=" + explination + ", from=" + from + '}';
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
     Ban x = new Ban(new Date(), new Date(), "Transient means do not serialize.", "Thorn");
     File f = new File("test.out");
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
     out.writeObject(x);
     out.close();

     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
     Ban fromFile = (Ban) in.readObject();
     System.out.println(fromFile);
     in.close();
  }
```

}

The output produced is:

```
 Ban{start=null, end=null, explination=Transient means do not serialize., from=Thorn}
```

Note that the output has both dates as null even though I gave them values. A **transient** value is not serialized.

Comment: I ran the code without an error. If I got the same exception you did then the output pasted into my answer would not have been produced. Try copying and pasting my code and running it.

Answer (score 0):

The transient keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized.
See this post for more details [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables)

Without your error cpde we cannot assist you

Answer (score 0):

transient variables cannot be serialized.

Comment: Can you clarify how/why this is?

Comment: transient is a Java keyword specifically created to exclude variables from serialization. Remove it and you can potentially serialize a variable. There are many beginner introductions to the topic try the SCJP book by Bates and Sierra

Answer (score 0):

The `transient` fields are not serialized, they will be `null` after reading from a stream. The error seems to come from an inner class named `Main` which is missing in your code example and not implement `Serializable`!