# Can I wrap a non-serializeable class in a local nested serializeable class?

Tags: java, serialization, nested-class

I was wondering, if I can cheat serialization by wrapping them in local nested classes, something like this:

I have a service which I need to pass around, but it internally has some very complex data.

```
 interface ComplexService {
       IncredibleComplexObject getData();
   }
```

So I thinking about wrapping it in another class that is serializeable via decorator pattern.

```
public final class Utils {

   public static Serializable wrap(final ComplexService service) {
       class WrapperService implements ComplexService, Serializeable {
           @Override
           public IncredibleComplexData getData() {
                return service.getData();
           }
       };
       return new WrapperService();
   }
}
```

I actually don't believe that I can cheat serialization like that, because it would be a little bit too much magic if Java could actually recreate my class that is dependent on my final ComplexService-parameter. But I am wondering, why exactly this fails and what exception would be thrown, where and why.

---

(just for clarification why I would want to do this: I am on android and I need to pass this service to a Fragment, which naturally can only save serializeable objects).

Comment: Can't ComplexService be serializable too (i.e. extend Serializable)?

Comment: `ComplexService` itself can't be serializable, because its actual implementation caches the `IncredibleComplexObject` in a field, thus would not be serializable.

Comment: and can't IncredibleComplexObject be serializable? :P 
Anyway, after you wrap it in WrapperService, how will you be able to call getData() from outside? It's an inner-method-class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap your non-serializable object in a serializable wrapper. No, it won't magically make the wrapped object serializable. You'll get a [`NotSerializableException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) if you attempt to serialize the wrapper class (without making that field [`transient`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5245600/2970947)).

Comment: In my example my wrapper class actually does not have any fields, so I would expect that serialization still works, but deserialization would likely cause an exception, am I wrong?

Comment: Funny thing, i just tried it out and you are right - I don't get an exception when deserializing - I am already getting an exception when serializing. Why we should not serialize inner classes anyway, is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17805016/1406325