# Why does my "marshaller" have to be "static"?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to "marshall" and "unmarshall" objects, in their own class, and using a "Marshaller".

**The Main method :**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Something();        
    }
}
```

The "Something" class that will produce the instances to marshall or unmarshall :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Something implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int value = 2;
    private File file = new File("something.serial");
    private static Marshaller marshaller = new Marshaller();

    Something() {

        value = 3;
        marshaller.marshalling(file, this);
        Something anotherThing = (Something) marshaller.unmarshalling(file);
        System.out.println(anotherThing.value);
    }
}
```

**Here is the Marshaller :**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Marshaller {

    public Marshaller() {

}

    /**
     * Charge l'objet sérializé d'un fichier si il existe
     * @param file : le fichier à désérialiser
     * @return obj : l'instance d'objet désérialisé
     */
    public Object unmarshalling(File file) {
        Object obj = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois;
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(file));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    /**
     * Permet d'enregistrer un objet (settings, client...) dans un fichier
     * @param file : le fichier support de la sérialisation
     * @param obj : l'instance d'objet à sérialiser
     * 
     */
    public void marshalling(File file, Object obj) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(file)));
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the class `Something`, if my Marshaller isn't declared "static", I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException`. Why ?

Thank you for your answers to help me to understand.

Have a good day.

PS : Shall I use the word `marshall` or `serialize` ?

Comment: If your `Marshaller` is in an instance field of `Something`, then it will try to be serialized when the `Something` is serialized, because it is part of that instance of `Something`. If it is static, it is not part of the instance, so it does not need to be serialized.

Comment: You could try using the `transient` [keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245600/what-does-the-keyword-transient-mean-in-java) to prevent it from serializing.

Comment: Note that you could make the `marshalling` and `unmarshalling` utility methods `static` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you serialize an object, all of the objects that are reachable from that object are stored as well, so all of them must be `serializable`. If you declare your class like:

```
public class Something implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int value = 2;
    private File file = new File("something.serial");
    private Marshaller marshaller = new Marshaller();
}
```

Then reachable fields from any instance of class `Something` are `value`, `file` and `marshaller`, so jvm will try to serialize them as well, which requires each of them must be `serializable`, but class `Marshaller` is not, then exception happens.

When you declare a field as `static`, you make it a member of the class, not individual instance, since serialization only cares about the current state of instances, only data associated with a specific instance will be serilized, therefore all static fields are ignored and your program works OK.

If you do need a field be instance member but don't want it to be serialized, you need to declare it with keyword `transient`, then it'll be ignored during the serialization.

And for the word `marshall` and `serialize`, I'm not a native English speaker so I cann't tell too much about the difference between them, but personally I prefer `serialize` in this case, and use `marshall` when dealing JSON/XML from/to java objects.

Hope this could be helpful to you :-)

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you.